# Adding Footnote to the Index Title

Tags: footnotes, titles, indexing, imakeidx

I am using `imakeidx` package and now I need to add footnote to the title of one index. Is there a way to do that?

Basically I need an asterisk next to the title of one index and explanation in the footnote below.

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
     citecolor=black,
     filecolor=black,
     linkcolor=black,
     urlcolor=black
}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[style=historische-zeitschrift, maxnames=2, hyperref=true, backref=true, backrefstyle=none, backend=biber, idemtracker=true]{biblatex}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\indexsetup{level=\section*,toclevel=section,headers={Stellenregister}{\indexname},firstpagestyle=scrheadings}%
\makeindex[name=band1-bibelstellen,title=Biblische Bücher\protect\footnote{Bücher}, columns=4, intoc, columnsep=15pt]
\makeindex[name=band1-patrquellen,title=Patristische Schriften, columns=4, intoc, columnsep=8pt]
\makeindex[name=band1-themen,title=Themen, intoc, columnsep=8pt]
\makeindex[name=band1-personen,title=Personen, intoc, columnsep=15pt]
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\pagebreak
\blindtext\index[band1-patrquellen]{First!Second!Third}
\blindtext\index[band1-bibelstellen]{First!Second!Third}
\blindtext\index[band1-themen]{First!Second!Third}
\printindex[band1-bibelstellen]
\printindex[band1-patrquellen]
\printindex[band1-themen]
\printindex[band1-personen]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please make your code compilable. The `one.ist` file isn't available. `title=Biblische Bücher\protect\footnote{Bücher}`should work

Comment: I edited my MWE to exclude one.ist now. As for your proposal it does add footnote to the title but it also adds text of the footnote to the bookmarks and footnote number to the table of contents. Any suggestions how to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bit of a kludge, but you could patch `\imki@putindex` temporarily to manually specify what should be added to the table of contents.

Here's a MWE showing how to do it. Just load `etoolbox` then patch `\imki@putindex` before your call to `\printindex`. Put both the `\patch` command and the `\printindex` command in braces to make sure the change is local only.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[nonewpage]{imakeidx}
\makeindex[title=Index\protect\footnote{A footnote},intoc]
\begin{document}
\null\vfill
\tableofcontents
\index{Filler text}
{% patch printing of heading in TOC to leave out footnote
 \makeatletter
 \patchcmd{\imki@putindex}
   {\imki@title}
   {Index}% <- specify your desired TOC entry here
   {}
   {}
 \makeatother
 \printindex
}
% compare with index title printed with footnote in TOC
\printindex
\end{document}
```

[image]